# Combining Different Inputs in a Neural Network for Numerical Integration

Tags: neural-networks, convolution

I am building a NN that numerically integrates a non-linear differential equation. Given a DE: $$
\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = f(x, p)
$$
with solution $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and parameters $p \in \mathbb{R}^m$, it takes $x(0)$ and $p$ as inputs and guesses $x(T)$ for some time $T$.

I have a couple ideas for the architecture of the NN and am looking for guidance on the best route. *What I'm primariliy confused about is how to combine $x(0)$ and $p$ in the NN*. I can think of some ways to do this practically, but I'm not sure what is the theoretically strongest approach.

**Idea 1:** Concatenate $x(0)$ and $p$ and apply an $(n+m)$ x $n$ layer before passing on to other layers for further processing.

**Idea 2:** Apply an n x n layer to $x(0)$, an m x n layer to $p$, and then either add or convolve the two resulting vectors before passing them on to further layers.